# Creating Replica vf page of New Lead

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead" extensions="SourceMDMLeadPageController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:sectionHeader subtitle="New Lead" title="Lead Edit"/>
        <apex:pageMessages escape="false"></apex:pageMessages>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Lead Edit" >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!saverecord}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Lead Information" columns="2" collapsible="false" >
                <apex:inputfield value="{!campmem.campaignID}"/>
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Owner"/>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!u}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Phone"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Phone}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel >First Name</apex:outputLabel>
                <apex:outputLabel >
                <!--<apex:selectList size="1" value="{!selectedfirstName }">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!FirstNamelist}"/>
                </apex:selectList> -->
                <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Salutation}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.FirstName}" />
                </apex:outputLabel>
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Mobile"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.MobilePhone}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Last Name"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.LastName}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Fax"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Fax}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Company"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Company}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Email"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Email}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Title"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Title}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Website"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Website}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Lead Source"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.LeadSource}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Status"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Status}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Status"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Rating}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Status"/>
              <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Industry}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="No. of Employees"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.NumberOfEmployees}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Annual Revenue"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.AnnualRevenue}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>


            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Allow Duplicates"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.AllowDuplicates_Mdm__c}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Candidate Key"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Candidate_Key__c}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
                   <apex:pageBlockSection title="Adress Information" columns="1" collapsible="false" >
                   <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Street"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Street}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.City}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="State/Province"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.State}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Zip/Postal Code"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.PostalCode}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Country"/>

            <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Country}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Additional Information" columns="2" collapsible="false" >         
                <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                    <apex:outputLabel value="Description"/>
                    <apex:inputField value="{!CurentLeadRec.Description}"/> 
                </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Class

```
public SourceMDMLeadPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   this.CurentLeadRec = (Lead)controller.getRecord();     
   system.debug('*** CurentLeadRec  *****'+CurentLeadRec  );
}
```

I am not able create lookup field of Campaign in this Page..need help.

Comment: How do you set value in `campmem`

Answer (score 0):

Have you define it in your extension?

```
public CampaignMember campmem {get;set;}

public SourceMDMLeadPageController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   this.CurentLeadRec = (Lead)controller.getRecord();     
   system.debug('*** CurentLeadRec  *****'+CurentLeadRec  );
   campmem = new CampaignMember();

}
```